# How to modify a rowconcat function?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I found the following function on a website. For a particular column, this function gives the column values as comma separated values like a,b,c,d and so on. Is there a way where I can get these values as 'a','b','c','d' and so on.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rowconcat(q in VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    ret  VARCHAR2(4000);
    hold VARCHAR2(4000);
      cur  sys_refcursor;
    BEGIN
      OPEN cur FOR q;
      LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO hold;
        EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
        IF ret IS NULL THEN
           ret := hold;
        ELSE
           ret := ret || ',' || hold;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN ret;
END;
```

I have already tried

```
IF ret IS NULL THEN
   ret := '''|| hold || ''';
ELSE
   ret := ret || ',' || '''||hold || ''';
END IF;
```

The result that it gives me is

```
'|| hold || ','||hold || ','||hold || ','||hold || ','||hold || ','||hold || ','||hold || ','||hold || ','||hold || ','||hold || and so on.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following part of the function,

```
    IF ret IS NULL THEN
       ret := hold;
    ELSE
       ret := ret || ',' || hold;
    END IF;
```

with this,

```
    IF ret IS NULL THEN
       ret := ''''|| hold ||'''';
    ELSE
       ret := ret || ',' || ''''||hold || '''';
    END IF;
```

Comment: This won't work Mani. The problem lies with the delimiter. Isn't there a symbol that forces a value read. Now, the code is not forcing a read on hold. It's taking the first ' and the last ' and printing whatever lies in between.

Comment: Sorry, i missed 1 quote while typing. add ''''|| hold || ''''